# trying to login to a window with a pop up Frame to handle cookies to accept/reject

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am practising for javascript selenium nd trying to open a window with iframe popup to manage cookies accept/reject all buttons.

```
await driver.navigate().to('https://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/');
await driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
await driver.sleep(2000)
await driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id=\"save\"]/span[1]/div/span\']')));
await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id=\"save\"]/span[1]/div/span\']')).click();
await driver.sleep(5000);
```

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong here. It opens new window and after few seconds shuts down. Can someone help me with how to handle the iframe.

Comment: Try this no idea whether it works or not. when you launch the browser that time you create another Tab(i'e Child Tab) and once your all activity is done in the parent Tab just switch to this child tab and pass the child Tab URL.